# Python Pandas DF Pivot and Groupby

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, pivot-table

I need to iterate through my dataframe rows and pivot the single column bounding_box_y into 8 columns each time the value in text_y column changes.

original data frame

[image]

desired data frame

[image]

Can anyone help with some code that does NOT hardcode values into the code?  The entire dataframe is over 6000 rows.  I need to pivot the one column into 8 each time the value in another column changes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Please try to include your data as callable code, so others can easily copy/paste and experiment. In your case you can get it with `df.head(16).to_dict('list')`. I used the following

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'boundingBox_y': [183, 120, 305, 120, 305, 161, 182, 161, 318, 120, 381, 120, 382, 162, 318, 161],
    'text_y': (['FORM'] * 8) + (['ABC'] * 8),
    'confidence': ([0.987] * 8) + ([0.976] * 8)
    })
```

Then you can `pivot` your dataframe but you need to add a new column to hold the pivoted column names.

```
# rename the current values column
df.rename({'boundingBox_y': 'value'}, axis=1, inplace=True)

# create a column that contains the columns headers and can be pivoted
df['boundingBox_y'] = df.groupby(['confidence', 'text_y']).transform('cumcount')

# pivot your df
df = df.pivot(index=['confidence', 'text_y'],
    columns='boundingBox_y', values='value')
```

Output

```
boundingBox_y        0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7
confidence text_y
0.976      ABC     318  120  381  120  382  162  318  161
0.987      FORM    183  120  305  120  305  161  182  161
```

Comment: Thank you.  I am trying to do this without listing the data points in the code.  This is because there are over 6000 rows in the table that need to be pivoted at various points but always when the row data changes. I need to iterate through the 6000 rows and instead of having 8 repeating rows of data with a different bounding box coordinate in each row, I want one row of data with 8 bounding box columns.

Comment: Pleas edit your question and explain how this output is different from your desired result, I'm having trouble understanding what you want...

Comment: Hi Richie, the boundingBox_y values look hard coded. How can I get it to iterate through the dataframe without hard coding the values?

Comment: What do you mean by "hardcoded'? The `transform` line will create as many ids as are needed, so there might be more than 8 columns in your data... have yout tried it? If it is not the result you expect please, edit your question and show the outcome with this code and the full data, and explain what needs to be improved

Comment: Hello, I did try the code and it produces the correct result for only the first 16 rows of values I included in my sample data.  I get the result you posted in "Output." But I need more than the two rows.  I need it to iterate through 6000 rows and it is not iterating.

Comment: I know it is hard to convey the problems in a comment, so please edit your question and post the output of this code with your data, and explain why it is not the expected output